# Type error to create and update my list in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I'm trying to use my api to create and update products in a bundle. I did so:

model.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)

class Product(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(
        Business,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"



class Bundle(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(
        Business,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="bundles",blank=True, null=True, through="BundleProduct")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Bundle"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BundleProduct(models.Model):

    bundle = models.ForeignKey(Bundle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bundleproducts")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bundleproducts")
    number = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Bundle of Product"


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product.name) + " do " + self.bundle.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("BundleProduct_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

And here is my serializers.py:

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"        

class BundleProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BundleProduct
        fields = "__all__"


class BundleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bundle
        fields = "__all__"
```

My viewset.py

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    model = Product


class BundleProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = BundleProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BundleProductSerializer
    model = BundleProduct


class BundleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Bundle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BundleSerializer
    model = Bundle
```

When I try to post some products in bundleproducts I receive "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."

Reading about this error, I found some issues relating to PrimaryKeyRelatedField and SlugRelatedField. I know I need to override but I have no idea how to do it.

It's an example of how to post would works:

```
{
    "number": 1,
    "bundle": 2,
    "product": 
         [
            1,
            2
         ]
}
```

After watching the video commented by Neil, I created the following method:

```
class BundleSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products = validated_data.pop('products')
        bundle = BundleProduct.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product in products:
            BundleProduct.objects.create(**product, bundle=bundle)
        return Bundle


    class Meta:
        model = Bundle
        fields = "__all__"
```

But doesn't work. I receive this error: "TypeError at /api/v1/bundle/

'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Can you provide, how you send post?

Comment: @HeadmasterI just update my question with a post example.

Comment: Are you trying to make post to BundleSerializer or BundleProductSerializer since you are saying. When I try to post some products in bundleproducts I receive "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."

Comment: In the BundleSerializer. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you  trying to also create products from BundleSerializer or just pass id of products already Created ?

Comment: Just pass the IDs. Products are created at another endpoint. I just wanted to pass some IDs like "products = [1, 2, 3]". @bkawan

Comment: I have posted the answers Please have a look. @JoeyFran

Comment: Hey, @bkawan I just answered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making post via BundleSerializer you need to pass products  with list of ProductSerializer data not just id since products in BundleSerializer is accepting productsSerializer data. You are getting **type error 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"** because your validated_data contain name and BundleProduct object Does not have name field.And you are creating BundleProduct objects with validated_data.

Create bundle object and pass id of bundle object to BundleProduct object.

- If you do not want to create product and just pass existing product id you need to make ListField
- You need to Override **get_fields** and check the requests
- override **to_representation** to return always List of ProdutSerializer Data
- Override **create** for **POST** request
- Override **update** for **PUT** and **PATCH** Request

Below is solution for **POST** Request

For **PATCH** AND **PUT** Request you need to override update method of ModelSerializer and handle the products accordingly.

```py
class BundleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products = validated_data.pop('products')
        bundle = Bundle.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_id in products:
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
            BundleProduct.objects.create(product=product, bundle=bundle)
        return bundle

    class Meta:
        model = Bundle
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        repr = super().to_representation(instance)
        repr['products'] = ProductSerializer(instance.products.all(), many=True).data
        return repr

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        if self.context['request'].method in ['POST', "PATCH","PUT"]:
            fields['products'] = serializers.ListField(
                write_only=True,
                child=serializers.IntegerField()
            )
        return fields
```

sample POST data to BundleSerializer

```
{
    "products":[1,2],
    "name":"Offer One",
    "description":"description",
    "price":1212,
    "business":1

}
```

Comment: Hello @bkwan. Thanks a lot for your help. I applied the code and works fine. I just have one question. In POST I receive a status_code 201. It's ok, but the Bundle does not appear in API (browser API, insomnia, postman) only appear in django-admin interface.

Comment: Do you mean bundle Object after post ?

Comment: Yes. I can access it by django admin interface, but not by API browser (it's empty). @bkawan

Comment: Please show me image. I did not get you quite right.

Comment: I put the images [here](https://share.riseup.net/#qanG4qUaCVEeh0k1fa56Og) "/api/v1/bundle/" and [here](https://share.riseup.net/#1IEi2ZPiKJVzJ-o_TXarPA) "/project/admin/bundle/". @bkawan

Comment: please check you endpoint it is fine when i ran. May be you have problem with ViewSet. Please post your viewset class.

Comment: thanks again. I review my code and I found a type error. It works fine.

Comment: Hello @bkwan. When I try access '/api/v1/docs/' I receive this error 'AttributeError at api/v1/docs/' - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'. The line is relative to `if self.context['request'].method in ['POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT']:`. Do you would has some idea?

Comment: Hello @JoeyFran, you need to pass request in serializer when instantiating like as below. There are other ways too.
serializer = BundleSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request':request})

Comment: Hello again @bkawan. Do I just need to pass that line in a view? or do I need to create a method? What is 'qs'?

Comment: qs is list of query,  if object pass object and remove many=False, I do not know how is your view. using serializer. You can post views and will let you know.

Comment: My view code ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869055/type-error-to-create-and-update-my-list-in-django-rest-framework)) is the same. I tried to pass in BundleViewset, but the 'qs' is not found...

Comment: I tried `serializer = BundleSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})` in my view, but the error continues.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you want to update a model and a related model in one request, with DRF, the easiest way to do this is to override the "create" method of a serializer. There's a good video on this here which I used as my reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyMFf9O6E60

Comment: Hi Neil, I saw the video and I think I made some progress. But my "create" method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are posting a list to `BundleProduct`'s product field yet it is an `ForeignKey`. To join `Bundle` to a `Product`, simply `POST`:

```
{
  "bundle": 2,
  "product" 1,
  "number": 1
}
```

You can repeat this:

```
{
  "bundle": 2,
  "product" 4,
  "number": 1
}
```

to add yet another product 4 to the same bundle and so on. Just make sure you do them one by one and not in a list as you had done earlier.

Comment: Ok, thanx. But I need to send this data in an only POST.

Comment: @JoeyFran Not sure I get your question but yest it should be a POST request

Comment: My need would be to pass on single multiple POST products to the bundle. An example "products: [1, 2, 3]".