# Error to update PATCH in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After many research and great help (thanks @bkawan), I got write my method create in drf serialization many to many. My challenge now is to make my method "update" work.

The PUT works fine, but the PATCH doesn't work when I exclude the product field.

Does someone have any idea? My serializer.py, views and create method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869055/type-error-to-create-and-update-my-list-in-django-rest-framework/54884736?noredirect=1#comment96552520_54884736).

And here is my idea for update:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        products = validated_data.pop('products', None)

        if products is not None:
            BundleProduct.objects.filter(bundle=instance.id).delete()

            for product_id in products:
                product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
                BundleProduct.objects.create(product=product, bundle=instance)

        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Why you're deleting and Creating the same record every time, whenever you're updating. I don't what exactly you're doing, but that's not mandatory and waste of time. Use the below code it will work for both `Update` and 
`Patch` methods.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**PUT** - You need to send all the expected records in the serializer.

**PATCH** - Send `id` and required fields to update.

For further reference, [refer this](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.mixins/UpdateModelMixin.html#update)