# I receive typerror when use request method in drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request

With some help, I solved this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869055/type-error-to-create-and-update-my-list-in-django-rest-framework/54884736?noredirect=1#comment96552520_54884736).

My api is work, but today I found this error when I try to access '/api/v1/docs'

```sh
AttributeError at /api/v1/docs/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'
```

I know that the error is here:

```py
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        if self.context['request'].method in ['POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT']:
            fields['products'] = serializers.ListField(
                write_only=True,
                child=serializers.IntegerField()
            )
        return fields
```

When I remove `.method`, the access to the `/api/v1/docs/` works, but my solution to post some products in bundleproducts, doesn't work.

My code:

view.py

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    model = Product


class BundleProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = BundleProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BundleProductSerializer
    model = BundleProduct


class BundleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Bundle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BundleSerializer
    model = Bundle
```

Comment: Can you add the complete view code?

Comment: Hello, @JPG. I just update with my view code.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by this serializer being used as a nested serializer in another serializer. So lets say the definition for the serializer in question is:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
```

And you have another serializer like this:

```
class OtherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = MySerializer()
```

In this case, when instantiating an instance of **OtherSerializer**, its context is not passed automatically to **MySerializer**, so there would not be a request in the context of **MySerializer**. You can either add the context to nested serializer manually, or in the **get_fields** method, check that request exists in **self.context** and proceed accordingly.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you provide a field with

```
write_only=True
```

in serializer class definition, the field would not be present when reading the serializer, i.e for get requests in general, which seems like what you are trying to do here. So adding the **products** field as **write_only** would have the same effect, you do not need to override **get_fields** method

Comment: Hello. Thank you. With your help, I did a search about nested serializer and how to pass a context to serializer child. I tried to use `def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}`  to pass the context, but doesn't work.